# Javascript 'this' to pass a canvas to function when Page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, user-controls, this

I'm trying to pass the HTML canvas element as a parameter to a function, and I thought using the 'this' keyword would work, but I'm having trouble with it. Can someone please assist me in using the 'this' keyword to pass the canvas element to the 'Move()' function when the page loads?

```
<div id="Container">
   <canvas id="Chart" class="Chart" width="400" height="400" onload="Move(this)"></canvas>
</div>

   function Move(element) {
   console.log(element);
   }
```

I want to access the canvas's id, but I am getting null. I don't want to use other methods like 'getElementById', 'getElementsByClassName', or 'getElementsByTagName', as the canvas is inside a user control, and it may be problematic when dealing with multiple instances of the user control.

How can I pass the HTML canvas element as a parameter to the Move() function when the page loads using the onload attribute, and how can I access the canvas's id without using those other methods?

Comment: I think this needs more clarification. What does "the canvas is inside a user control" mean exactly? Using some form of `get` or `query` is basically the only way to interact with document elements, so not wanting to do the normal thing feels like a potential [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) requiring a very clear explanation of the use case and application context.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas does not have `onload` function, you can though call it on window onload

```
function move() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("Chart");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", move);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage

Comment: I don't want to use other methods like 'getElementById', 'getElementsByClassName', or 'getElementsByTagName', as the canvas is inside a user control, and it may be problematic  when dealing with multiple instances of the user control.